# Wait for a canceled task to complete before continuing execution

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asynchronous, task, cancellation

I have the following code, where a `Task` can be canceled, but I basically need to wait for it to complete (to ensure integrity) before throwing the `OperationCanceledException` to the caller.

```
public static void TaskCancellationTest() {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTest started.");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var t = Task.Run(() => {
            if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
            Console.WriteLine("3");
            Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("4");
        });
        Task.Run(() => {
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelling...");
            cts.Cancel();
        });
        t.Wait();
        try {
            cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            Console.WriteLine("Gracefully canceled.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTest completed.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTest... Failure: " + ex);
    }
}
```

The result, as expected, is:

```
1
Cancelling...
2
Gracefully canceled.
```

It works, but I would prefer to pass the `CancellationToken` to the methods as I understand this is a better pattern. I would also like to be able to observe the token inside the method body and to call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` to abort without having to wait for the next `ContinueWith(`).

I was playing with the following alternative code, which also works, but is there any way to have an `OperationCanceledException` raised instead of an `AggregateException`?

If I pass the cancellationToken to the `WaitAll()` method, the problem is that it will throw an `OperationCanceledException` immediately upon cancellation of the token, rather than waiting for the tasks `t1` and `t2` to actually complete (they will continue running in the background) and then only throwing the exception.

```
public static void TaskCancellationTest2() {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTest2 started.");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var t1 = Task.Run(() => {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }, cts.Token);
        var t2 = t1.ContinueWith(task => {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
            Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Console.WriteLine("4");
        }, cts.Token);
        Task.Run(() => {
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelling...");
            cts.Cancel();
        });
        try {
            try {
                Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae) {
                if (ae.InnerExceptions.Count == 1 && ae.InnerExceptions.Single() is OperationCanceledException) {
                    throw ae.InnerExceptions.Single();
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            Console.WriteLine("Gracefully canceled.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTest2 completed.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTest2... Failure: " + ex);
    }
}
```

I have prepared a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7ITSe).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997166/how-to-wait-for-canceled-task-to-finish)'s title is very similar to mine, but the accepted answer is unfortunately not relevant to my case.

Do you know of any way to achieve what I would like, that makes as good use of `CancellationToken` as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the TPL is designed to eagerly complete tasks if the `CancellationToken` is set. Part of the reason you are seeing this behavior is because you are calling `t.Wait(cts.Token)`. The overload that takes a `CancellationToken` will stop waiting if the token is set even if the task hasn't ran to completion.

It's the same with `ContinueWith` if you pass in a `CancellationToken` the task can complete as soon as that token is set.

Change your code to call `t.Wait()` and  `ContinueWith` without a token and you'll get the behavior you want.

```
    public static void TaskCancellationTestNotWorking1()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTestNotWorking started.");
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("2");
            }, cts.Token).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("3");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Console.WriteLine("4");
            });

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Cancelling...");
                cts.Cancel();
            }, cts.Token);

            try
            {
                t.Wait();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IsCanceled " + t.IsCanceled);
                Console.WriteLine("IsCompleted " + t.IsCompleted);                    

                Console.WriteLine("Gracefully canceled.");
            }
            catch (AggregateException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IsCanceled " + t.IsCanceled);
                Console.WriteLine("IsCompleted " + t.IsCompleted);

                Console.WriteLine("Gracefully canceled 1.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTestNotWorking completed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TaskCancellationTestNotWorking... Failure: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

You might find this article useful [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx)

Comment: If I don't call `t.Wait()`, then `Console.WriteLine("2");` will execute asynchronously after `TaskCancellationTestNotWorking()` will have returned. This is what I need to avoid (if I were writing a file instead of writing "2", I would need to make sure `TaskCancellationTestNotWorking()` would not return until after the  file writing operation were complete).

Comment: `IsCompleted` will return true if the task is in `Canceled` state, although it may still be executing code.

Comment: You have already called `Wait()` and it has thrown an exception, why would you call it again?

Comment: You could also replace `Task.Delay(2000).Wait();` with `Thread.Sleep(2000)`

Comment: I know `Wait()` is not working, but the objective is to really wait for the task to complete (even after being canceled) before returning, to avoid ghost operations to be performed after the method has returned.

Comment: Much clearer indeed, now the ideal would be if it were possible to have an OperationCanceledException directly raised upon waiting for the task instead of an AggregateException, as is the case when a cancellationToken is passed to Wait() (but which is then raised too early). I have updated my question accordingly but I have the feeling that there is no better way than what we found out.

Comment: Also an ancillary problem was that I was waiting for the continuation, not the original task (or both)! So as soon as the cancellationToken was cancelled, waiting on the continuation would return immediately (even if I had not specified any cancellationToken for the first task).

Comment: You can avoid getting the `AggregateException` by using async/await. When you await something that throws an `AggregateException` basically only the first exception is rethrown. But for that you require .NET 4.5 or the Async CTP.